# UI геометрия Transform: рассчитать rotate от текущих значений

Tags: ui, transform

Есть например объект со значением `transform scale 1.66`, нам надо установить ему `scale 1.0`. Проблема в том, что мы **не можем установить абсолютное значение, а только относительное**: то есть если мы проскейлим `1.66` до `1.0`, то получим `1.66 (1.66 * 1.0 = 1.66)`. Значит мы должны найти неизвестное: `1.66 * x = 1.0`. Тут все просто: `x = 1.0 / 1.66` (целевое значение / текущее значение).

Теперь мне надо сделать то же самое с `rotate`.

Мне нужна формула расчета где у нас известно текущее значение `rotate` и целевое значение, на выходе формула должна давать значение rotate, которое нужно применить к объекту чтобы получить целевое значение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Формул:

```
(target_rotation - current_rotation) % 360
```

где:

target_rotation - целевое значение поворота,
current_rotation - текущее значение поворота,
% - оператор остатка от деления, он нужен для преобразования результата в диапазон от 0 до 359 градусов.

пример:
current_rotation = 45
target_rotation = 90
result = (90 - 45) % 360 = 45

Или такая формула (но учтите, если текущее и целевое значение находятся в разных полукругах, то результат может быть меньше нуля, если это так, использ. модуль result = abs(result)

```
result = target_rotation - current_rotation
```

Comment: Большое спасибо